# Should we have a tag for Wendy's Feast of Legends RPG?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

Wendy's has released an RPG called [Feast of Legends](https://www.feastoflegends.com/images/Feast_Of_Legends.pdf). It's a hilarious and incredibly good parody of D&D but it's also a legitimate RPG in its own right.

Should we have a tag for it or just enjoy the joke and move on?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link.

Comment: This might be the most legit RPG ever.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## If someone asks a question about it, we can have a tag about it

We have tags for other jokey systems (or at least one, see [dungeons-the-dragoning](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeons-the-dragoning)), but tags can't exist (for more than a day) without at least one question with that tag. So if someone asks a question about Feast of Legends, then the tag can be created.

Comment: I hope to play test this with some friends soon, and have down loaded the pdf. Perhaps we will have one ..

Comment: Dungeons the Dragoning?  Heck,  We've got a tag for Human Occupied Landfill.  Compared to that one, Dungeons the Dragoning is positively *sane*.

Comment: Well, such a question [has been asked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157433/52137).

Comment: @som And it is such a good question, too lol